# How to break a arraylist into two variables in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, arraylist

I am retrieving values from server side using ajax call and here is the formate of the arraylist retrieved from server side..

**[INCOMING,0,INETCALL,0,ISD,31.8,LOCAL,197.92,STD,73.2]**

Now as per my need i have to break this arraylist in two variables like this..

**var toc=INCOMING,INETCALL,ISD,LOCAL,STD**

**var callcost=0,0,31.8,197.92,73.2**

I am trying to do it using for loop but i am not getting exact logic...

Here is my code..

```
$(function () {    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'getdata',
        async: false,
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (data) {

            var values = [];
            values = data;    
            values = values.replace('[', '');
            values = values.replace(']', '');    
            var array = values.split(",");

            for (var i in array) {

            }
        }
    });
});
```

Please guys help me .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why the replace/split calls? It's already an array! :P

Comment: FYI, you're working with an _array_, not an _ArrayList_...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [$.isNumeric()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.isnumeric/) like,

```
var arr=['INCOMING',0,'INETCALL',0,'ISD',31.8,'LOCAL',197.92,'STD',73.2];
var str=[],
    num=[];
for(var i=0,len=arr.length;i<len;i++){
   $.isNumeric(arr[i]) ?  num.push(arr[i]) :  str.push(arr[i]);
}
console.log(num);// returns array of numbers use num.join(',') to get string
console.log(str);// returns array of string use str.join(',') to get string
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2jzCA/1/)

Comment: thank u very much sir ..One small doubt if i have to add each values in '' single quotes how to do that..

Comment: Use `.toString()` to make the `variable` as `string` Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString

Answer (score 1):

First off, the data seems to be an array already, just parse it with

```
var array = JSON.parse(data);
```

Or, if you have control over the server-side code too, make it return json-data instead of plain text. That way its a array ready to use when its passed into the callback!

If you want to get all numeric in the loop, use isNumeric, if its every other, do a %1 on the index, ie:

```
var a1 = [];
var a2 = [];
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
   if(i % 1 == 0){
     a1.push(array[i]);
   } else {
     a2.push(array[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: I would take some from this answer and some from Rohan Kumar, the isNumeric is helpful.

Comment: Absolutely, if its the numeric he want in one of the arrays and not every other, did not say so in the question! =)

Answer (score 0):

check this fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/2sGjZ/

```
var myArray = ['INCOMING','0','INETCALL','0','ISD','31.8','LOCAL','197.92','STD','73.2'];
    var tocArr = new Array();
    var callcostArr = new Array();
    var j = 0; var k= 0;
    for ( var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i = i + 1 ) {
        if(i % 2 == 1){
             tocArr[j] = myArray[ i ];
            j++;
        }else{
            callcostArr[k] = myArray[ i ];
            k++;
        }
    }
    var toc = tocArr.toString();
    var callcost = callcostArr.toString();
    alert( toc );
    alert( callcost );
```