# How to add each jquery array values inside the single quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a array in jquery.Now as per my need i have to add each array values into single quotes as ..

```
var toc='INCOMING','INETCALL','ISD','LOCAL','STD'
```

But at present i have values like this ..

```
var toc=INCOMING,INETCALL,ISD,LOCAL,STD
```

And here is my codes ..

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'getdata',
                async:false,
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(data) {

                    var values = [];
                    values = data;

                    values=values.replace('[','');
                    values=values.replace(']','');

                    var array = values.split(",");

                    for(var i=0,len=array.length;i<len;i++)
                    {
                        if($.isNumeric(array[i]))
                        {  
                            callcost.push(array[i]);   
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            toc.push(array[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    alert(toc);
                    alert(callcost);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Do the string really need to contain the ' characters?

Comment: And if you do 'need' them, I would reconsider my design. Even if you get this working, it doesn't seem very optimal.

Comment: try `var newtoc="'" + toc.join("','") + "'"; console.log(newtoc);`

Comment: Also, a tip that I stated in my answer on your other post ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19830441/how-to-break-a-arraylist-into-two-variables-in-jquery/19830530#19830530 ), Parse the data object with JSON.parse() to make it into an array, instead of doing replace/split calls! :)

Answer (score 0):

not sure if i got your question right but i guess you are messing up with all this replace/split/... logic. If the data object is an array just try this

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'getdata',
            async:false,
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data) {

                var array = JSON.parse(data);

                $.each(array, function(i, val){

                  if($.isNumeric(val)) {  
                    callcost.push(val);   
                  }else{
                    toc.push(val);
                  }

                });

            }
        });
```

Comment: thank u very much sir but i am getting this error SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
 

var array = JSON.parse(data);

Comment: your json seems to be invalid, do a console.log(data); or alert(data); before json parsing (before the "var array..." line) and lets see what you have ;)